# Как поставить ограничение на пуш в ветку гит?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Как поставить себя админом ветки в гит?

У нас есть человек который занимается мерджами и пушами в основную ветку и хочется сделать так, чтоб только у него была возможность делать пуш в основную ветку, а все остальные могли только сделать пулл с нее.

Как это реализовать в гит?

**ВАЖНО**

У нас своя серверная часть, мы не используем `gitlab`, `github` и т.д.

Я так понял, что можно это как то сделать с помощью хуков...

Есть пример? Туториал

Comment: А что используется на "серверной части" для git?

Comment: @KoVadim Я знаю гит со стороны пользователя... Не совсем понял вопрос. А что там может быть?

Comment: собственно, внизу уже ответили. GitLab/GitHub/или подобное.

Comment: @KoVadim у нас просто свой репозиторий на сервере, который не `GitLab` и не `GitHub` ... я думаю это просто репозиторий... Как это можно проверить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерно такой скриптик кинуть в `.git/hooks/update` сервера и дать ему права на выполнение.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$USER" != "git-repo-admin" ] && [ "$1" == refs/heads/master ];then
  echo "Manual pushing to this repo is restricted"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: А есть все же туториал или более подробная инструкция? А то не совсем понятно как это будет работать. Или подробнее опишите, что означает каждая строка и кстати это наложит ограничение на все проекты которые лежат на сервере или только на конкретный проект?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko на конкретный проект. А собственно что описать? Если юзер не git-repo-admin и пытается изменить хед мастера - вывести сообщение и остановить выполнение с кодом 1.

Comment: А что значит дать ему права на выполнение?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `chmod +x .git/hooks/update`

Comment: `refs/heads/master` я так понимаю, что вместо слова `master` может быть любое другое название ветки?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko да

Comment: Я так понимаю, что сама `git` дериктория скрыта, но она должна находиться на уровне проекта? верно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko да. Она и будет там находится. А `.` перед git означает, что директория скрыта (так уж повелось в юникс системах)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, не обязательно репо в каталоге `.git`. Вот вариант для полных извращенцев: создаем пустой репо: `git init --bare /tmp/bare.git`, затем переходим в рабочий каталог нашего репо и делаем: `git --git-dir=/tmp/bare.git --work-tree=. status`, выхлоп - ни одного коммита. Так мы указали в качестве репо новый репо, а рабочий каталог с файлами - текущий.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko да. И с этим новым репо можно работать. НО. В созданном нами репозитории как был закомичен мастер (в данном случае), так он и останется. Никто этого коммита не заметит. Или ты о том, что .git/... путь не всегда валидный? Так, в данном случае, это был просто пример (причем, все равно, в большенстве случаев все пользуются дефолтными параметрами, а значит, что в большенстве своем этот путь будет подходить). Ну а кто решил изменить каталог - он сам знает, что он делает

Comment: Нашел в этом проекте https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop вот такую имплементацию https://goo.gl/M8AFGC мне кажется это тоже должно работать? Что скажите?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko не будет. Грэдл - это система сборки проекта. Не особо представляю, как она может повлиять на репозиторий/коммиты. Более того, в пересланом вами файле идет конфигурация нексуса и сборки проекта (собственно, для чего и нужен грэдл), но ни слова не сказано о конфигурации гита

Comment: Мне показалось, что это проверка логина и пароля репозитория

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko да, но относятся к нексусу

Comment: Я вот добрался до этого скрипта и сейчас хочу его положить куда ты сказал, но у меня на сервере нет `hooks` вот, что находится на сервере в папке проекта в дирректории гит https://www.screencast.com/t/n2AMFaUsQ , где взять папку о которой ты говоришь?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko создай

Comment: `.git/hooks/update` hooks это папка, и `update` это файл я так понимаю в котором должен быть скрипт. А какой формат файла?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko просто файл с именем update. Без каких-то лишних символов.

Comment: все сделал, вот что получилось https://goo.gl/vo7HTy я специяально поставил не правильное имя, чтоб проверить если это работает и все равно он дает мне сделать пуш и пишет вот такую штуку https://goo.gl/v6Dx9C я так понимаю, что синтакс не правильный? Или что то пропустил? Может имя ветки не так указал?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko видимо не считывается USER. Попробуй REMOTE_USER или AUTH_USER.

Comment: Ошибка была в ковычках, я добавил в отвтет, но теперь какое бы имя юзера я не указал, я получаю отказ. А какие еще есть переменные? Может можно как то указать по мейлу? Я пробовал вместо `USER` указать `USER_NAME` , но все равно не пропускает

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko попробуй с помощью echo вывести значения, которые ты пытаешься сравнивать. Тогда будем понимать, в чем проблема

Comment: что ты думаешь об этом https://stackoverflow.com/a/53980939/5709159

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87677/discussion-between-anton-m-and-aleksey-timoshchenko).

Answer (score 3):

Никак. В ванильном git нет таких механизмов и можно только использовать организационные методы (приказом по организации запретить всем, кроме) - сами понимаете, так себе эффективность.

Если очень хочется -- посмотрите в сторону gitlab, он [умеет](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) подобные вещи.

В gitlab можно создавать [защищённые ветки (protected branches)](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/), обычно это какие-то релизные ветки.

Посмотреть можно на странице Repository - Branches:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расставить права можно перейдя по ссылке в настройки проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно указать кто имеет право на merge данной ветки (это и право сразу пушить в неё без оформления пулл-реквеста) - см. столбец Allowed to merge.

Comment: А разве gitlab не с гит работает?

Comment: Ох, надо АК ставить минус за дезинформацию (но не сегодня). 
Все можно сделать в гите, надо просто сделать правильные hook'и. И все будет так, как Вам хочется. Но только это должны быть хуки на стороне сервера, а то клиентские хуки сам пользователь может и потереть.

Comment: @KoVadim о, а есть туториал или что то? У нас своя серверная часть... Так что все можно, только понять бы как

Comment: @KoVadim Ставьте, я не против минусов если у меня где-то пробел. Насколько я знаю (поправьте меня если что) в самом гите нет никаких ни групп, ни раздачи прав. В хуках вы похоже хотите какой-то механизм реализовать которого нет в гите, типа проверку на имя пользователя?

Comment: да, на базе хуков и проверок. Но в самом гите действительно нет никаких групп/пользователей.

Comment: У голого git'а реозиторий публикуется как readonly, и владелец уже делает pull из репозитория разработчика после pull-request'а (по почте или иному коммуникационному каналу не в git)

Comment: Да, но мы не используем `gitlab` у нас своя серверная часть... Так, что это не совсем нам подойдет...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Тогда ориентируйтесь на решение, которое вам указывает KoVadim - пишите самописные хуки, в котором проверяйте username и ветку. Вот например, [посмотрите скрипт](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&hl=ru&ei=tXIXXOWoEvHSrgTI-55w&q=git+hook+prevent+push+to+master&oq=git+hook+prevent+push+to+master&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.202871.206365..206518...0.0..0.97.1086.18......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i13j0i8i7i30j0i7i30i19j0i8i7i30i19j0i13i30j0i8i13i30j0i30j0i22i30.8vm1jPekrBk) для pre-push из этой статьи в качестве затравки: https://blog.ghost.org/prevent-master-push/